# Transient Failure handling in .net core 2.1 MVC for MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(mysqlConnection,
    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
    {
        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
        maxRetryCount: 10,
        maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
        errorNumbersToAdd: null);
    });
});
```

I found this code snippet  at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/implement-resilient-entity-framework-core-sql-connections

My DB is MySQL 5.7

I changed the above code to :

[image]

That means EnableRetryOnFailure is not available for MySQL DB. How do i set the retry, delay etc.. policies now?

Also if i try to set the ExecutionStrategy function i get this:

[image]

Then i tried Create my own Strategy using:

```
public class MyStrategy: ExecutionStrategy
{
   ......
}
```

but how to use this class now?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a library for this:
https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Setup steps:

1. Donwload `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` from NuGet.
2. Add this using to your class:

   `using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;`
3. Add this to your `ConfigureServices` method:

   ```
   services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>( 
   options => options.UseMySql("Server=localhost;Database=ef;User=root;Password=123456;",

       mySqlOptions =>
       {
           mySqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Version(5, 7, 17), ServerType.MySql)
           .EnableRetryOnFailure(
           maxRetryCount: 10,
           maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
           errorNumbersToAdd: null); 
       }
   ));
   ```

Comment: I got this error:CS1061 'MySQLDbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ServerVersion' and no accessible extension method 'ServerVersion' accepting a first argument of type 'MySQLDbContextOptionsBuilder'

Comment: If you check the source on github, it seems like it is there: https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/blob/3ab23945fd389042aa0a8b522a95c8044bd2ec0b/src/EFCore.MySql/Infrastructure/MySqlDbContextOptionsBuilder.cs which version of nuget package did you donwnload?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using .NET 5, to avoid `does not contain a definition for 'ServerVersion'` you can use the following:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    string connectionString = AppConfig.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    options.UseMySql(connectionString,
        ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString),
        mySqlOptions =>
            mySqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                maxRetryCount: 10,
                maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                errorNumbersToAdd: null);
        );
});
```