# Asp.net Core Mysql 'connectionString' error

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, connection-string

I used entityframework to migrate my sql database but here is error to connect mysql host.

Error during run `context.Database.Migrate()` :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call.'
>
> Inner exception  MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

ConnectionString:

```
"ConnectionString": "Server=xxx.com; Port=3306; Database=xxxdb; Uid=xxxuser; Pwd=xxx***",
```

dbcontext configurator in Startup --> ConfigureServices method.

```
      services.AddDbContext<MasterContext>(
                    options => options.UseMySql(
                        settings.MasterDatabase.ConnectionString,
                        b => b.MigrationsAssembly("WebApi")
                    )
                );
```

dbcontext Migrate in Startup --> Configure method.

```
using (IServiceScope serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
{
       var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MasterContext>();
       context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how `settings` is resolved? Are you passing the real connection string?
(You can also hardcode the string to quickly test)

Comment: As the error text writes, you should enabling transient error resiliency, and then you will get a much more descriptive error message, which can help in debugging. Here you can find help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432473/transient-failure-handling-in-net-core-2-1-mvc-for-mysql-database

Comment: there is no error when i work on mysql localhost. it gives error on my mysql server connectionString.

Comment: then this could be a networking issue. can you connect to the databse using a gui-client?

Comment: @Riscie yes i can connect to mysql server with MySql Workbench.